# getting "Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined" error on jenkins console when jboss is trying to restart

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins, jboss

I have generated a war file using maven for one of my java projects, and tried to deploy it to jboss application server using jenkins CI/CD.

Getting below error on the jenkins console and it runs forever and doesn't come out of the build when jboss is restarted.

"Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined"

Below is the command used to start jboss:

```bash
cd /apps/jboss-eap-7.2/bin
nohup ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=5000 > nohup.out &
```

I have tried below options:

1. created a `logging.properties` file in src/main/resources folder and added below line:

   ```
   handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level= INFO
   ```
2. tried adding below dependancies in my pom.xml file:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

None of the above options worked.

I have uploaded the jenkins console log image of jboss-restart error part.
[jboss-restart-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQp4Q.png)

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: I am seeing this error on the jenkins console log : Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined

Comment: Are you trying to use logack in your deployment? The message is coming from something attempting to remove the console handler from the `java.utl.logging.LogManager`. It is likely some dependency. It's definitely not JBoss EAP doing this.

Comment: I am not using logback in my deployment . Irrespective of the Maven project , i have created a jenkins job to only restart jboss, still i get the the same error "Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined "

Comment: I have added below in my jenkins job configuration for restarting jboss:
 
 node {
  stage('restart jboss') {
     sshagent(['ssh_key_toconnectto_linuxserver']){ 
       sh """
                                    ssh -p 2022 -t usenams@password "bash /tmp/stop-jboss.sh"
                                    echo "Executing restart jboss script"
                                    ssh -p 2022 -t usenams@password "bash /tmp/start-jboss.sh"

                                """ }}}

Comment: Hello @JamesR.Perkins, this is the command i am using to start jboss :




 nohup /apps/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=5000&

Comment: I'm not too sure what that could be. It doesn't sound like a WildFly issue really. Do you have an example of the fully formatted log message?

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins , i have uploaded the jenkins console log of error in the image [jboss-restart-log] above.

Comment: Hmm... ...it's tough to tell where that is coming from. Do you use Spring in your application? Is it causing an issue or are you just trying to figure out where it's coming from?

Comment: I am not using spring in my application...it is a simple java application!! when i manually restart jboss from linux server, it works without any errors, i am getting this error only when i try to restart jboss from jenkins , so i am kind of guessing its coming from jboss but not the application.

Comment: It's definitely not coming from WildFly. It would be from an application deployed to WildFly, but WildFly does not use the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`. Nor does it make an attempt to remove any handlers in the `LogManager` unless there is a configuration difference between the `logging.properties` and the logging subsystem configuration.